# yytext equivalent in ocamllex

Tags: ocaml, yacc, lex

I have the following in my regular (not ocaml) yacc file:

```
wsorword         :  WS 
                    {
                      strcpy($$, yytext);
                    }
                 |  WORD
                    {
                      strcpy($$, yytext);
                    }
                 ;
```

How can I address the lexeme returned by WS or WORD in ocamllex/ocamlyacc?

Comment: Obligatory menhir comment: you should consider using [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) which is compatible with `ocamlyacc` grammars and better in all respects (lets you write more compact and readable grammars, helps you debug them, etc.). It can be used in combination with `ocamllex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define my tokens in the `mly` file as:

```
%token<string> WORD WS
```

in the `mll` file, I would use the following actions:

```
 rule lexer = parse
   | ws                    { WS (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) }
   | word                { WORD (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) }
```

where `ws` and `word` are the regexps for their respective tokens, of course.

Finally, the grammar rules become:

```
wsorword: 
  WS             { $1 }
| WORD        { $1 }
;
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, your yacc code is using a global variable provided by lex. OCaml doesn't prohibit globals, but they're not consistent with the functional way of writing code. If you make your lexical buffer global under the name `!lexbufr` (say), the manual says you can get the latest lexeme by calling `Lexing.lexeme !lexbufr`. Note that I haven't tried this myself.